# SQL operator "IN" is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Very simple problem. But still stuck from last couple of hours.

I have SQL query executing on MySQL (phpMyadmin) like:

```
SELECT * FROM `orderbook` WHERE (`order_to` IN ('49,6')) AND (`rate_change` = 'YES') ORDER BY `createdon` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Here I only get result matching with 49,
I change the order like (6,49) then I get result matching with 6 only..

Please help where I missing..

Thanks.
Prashant

Comment: For the future please read & act on [ask] and other [help] links but especially [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Should be:

```
IN (6, 49)  assuming this is a numeric column.
```

Comment: @gview is trying to tell you to remove the quotes around '6,49' or '49,6'. It should be `IN (6, 49)`, not `IN ('6, 49')`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IN` as this:

```
... WHERE (`order_to` IN (49, 6)) ...
```

Or if they are strings:

```
... WHERE (`order_to` IN ('49', '6')) ...
```

When you pass to an `IN` the value `'49,6'` it tries to match that exact string with the field value.

Answer (score 1):

As @gview and @JorgeCampos have said, you should not be quoting the list of numbers in your `IN` statement.

The reason it's partially working is because MySQL is trying to be clever. Because `order_to` is an integer, MySQL is trying to convert the string `'49,6'` to a number and getting `49`.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `orderbook` WHERE (`order_to` IN ('49,6'));
+----+----------+
| id | order_to |
+----+----------+
|  3 |       49 |
+----+----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '49,6' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select cast('49,6' as unsigned);
+--------------------------+
| cast('49,6' as unsigned) |
+--------------------------+
|                       49 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '49,6' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you working with wrong practice there you using '46,6' i expect that you want to search in both 46 and 6 if this true then use the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM `orderbook` WHERE (`order_to` IN ('49','6')) AND (`rate_change` = 'YES') ORDER BY `createdon` DESC LIMIT 10
```